# Chromecast - Album Art doesn't change

Tags: android, chromecast

I'm using a styled receiver for my chromecast receiver. When I select my first song to cast, the song and album art correctly shows up on the chromecast. However, when I changed the song, the album art stays the same. The song correctly changes, but the album art will not change. I upload the song and album art to a local HTTP server. When loading the server and port, the correct image shows up; however, it does not show up on the receiver. I suspect this is something to do with the MediaMetadata. This is how I load/change a song:

```
public void startSong(FileInputStream songFis, String title, String songUrl, String albumUrl, String contentType, int width, int height) {
    MediaMetadata mediaMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MUSIC_TRACK);
    mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, title);
    mediaMetadata.addImage(new WebImage(Uri.parse(albumUrl)));

    MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder(songUrl)
            .setContentType(contentType)
            .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
            .setMetadata(mediaMetadata)
            .build();
    try {
        mRemoteMediaPlayer.load(mApiClient, mediaInfo, true)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult mediaChannelResult) {
                        if (mediaChannelResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            mSongIsLoaded = true;
                        }
                    }
                });
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

I'm not all familiar with the chromecast sdk, so I'm not sure if I am doing something incorrect. I have browsed the sample projects, but I cannot spot what I am doing incorrectly.
Question: Why isn't the album art not changing on my chromecast receiver? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the albumArt variable is pointing to the correct value? Since it is your own receiver, you can open a chrome debugger session to see the logs and also inspect the <img> tag when a new son starts to see what the source is set to and take it from there.

Comment: The album art URL is always pointed to the same URL, which is the HTTP server/port. The image on that server simply changes when a new song is selected. But thanks, I'll check the debugger session.

Comment: Yes, I checked and the URL is alwayn pointed to the correct page. And the page does have the correct album art.

Comment: After some testing, it appears that the issue is I'm providing the same url, so the receiver believes it is the same image. By giving a different url, the image will properly change. However, I cannot change the URL for very image. How can I change the album art while still using the same URL?

Comment: Images are being cached so that is why you are getting the same image. Try this and see if it helps: prior to calling mediaMetadata.addImage(...), do: albumArt = albumArt + "?timestamp=" + System.currentTimeMillis(); and see what happens, basically you are making urls different enough to avoid cache reuse but still pointing to the same image. This is just a suggestion so see if that works for you or not

Comment: Thank you, that did indeed work.